# solving a function with series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-sum

Is it possible to find a solution for the following equation with respect to the parameter $\gamma_k$ where the equation is $$\alpha\gamma_k\beta_k-\alpha\ln\sum_{m=1}^K\exp(\gamma_m\beta_m)-\theta\gamma_k=0$$
where $\alpha$, $\theta$ and $\beta_i,i=\{1,...,K\}$ are constant?

Comment: is there a difference between $\gamma_k$ and $\gamma_K$?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes it is but I would like a closed-form and I am not interested in an exact solution. Even a decent approximation would be sufficient.

Comment: do you basically want to express $\gamma_k$ in terms of all other $\gamma_i, \alpha, \theta$ and $\beta_i$? Did you try it for $K=2$?

Comment: @gt6989b $k$ is 4 in my real problem.

Comment: @gt6989b the first two terms are basically the logarithm of a softmax function multiplied by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_K = \sum_{m=1}^K \exp(\gamma_m \beta_m)$, then you have
$$ \tag{*}
\alpha \gamma_K \beta_K - \alpha \ln (\exp(\gamma_K \beta_K) + s_{K-1}) - \theta \gamma_K = 0
$$
If $\alpha = 0$, the problem is trivial, so assume $\alpha \ne 0$. Divide (*) by $\alpha$ and substitute $x = \gamma_K \beta_K$ and $t = \frac{\theta}{\alpha \beta_K}$ to get
$$ \tag{**}
x - \ln (e^x + s_{K-1}) - tx = 0
$$
and we would like to solve this for $x$.

Now you can expand $f(x) = \ln(e^x+s)$ into [Maclaurin series (WolframAlpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+ln%28e%5Ex%2Bs%29) to get
$$
\begin{split}
\ln(e^x+s) 
 \approx \ln(s + 1)
       &+ \frac{x}{s + 1} + \frac{s x^2}{2 (s + 1)^2} \\
       &+ \frac{(s - 1) s x^3}{6 (s + 1)^3} + \frac{s (s^2 - 4 s + 1) x^4}{24 (s + 1)^4}\\
       &+ \frac{s (s^3 - 11 s^2 + 11 s - 1) x^5}{120 (s + 1)^5} \\
       &+ \frac{s (s^4 - 26 s^3 + 66 s^2 - 26 s + 1) x^6}{720 (s + 1)^6}
       + O(x^7)
\end{split}
$$
Take the quartic expansion and plug it into (**) and solve.